# Allowed Values in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am using a parameter to ask a user weather he wants a D drive or not, to do this I am using conditions.

I tried to give a Constraint Description and **Allowed Values** a parameter property.

```
  NeedVolumeD:
    Type: String
    Description: Do you want a D drive? Enter Yes or No
    ConstraintDescription: Enter Yes or No
    AllowedValues:
      - Yes
      - No
```

But this is giving me a dropdown of true and false whereas later in my code under Conditions I am trying to use Yes and No, although this is somehow working.

[image]

What am I not understanding here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **single quotes**:

```
  NeedVolumeD:
    Type: String
    Description: Do you want a D drive? Enter Yes or No
    ConstraintDescription: Enter Yes or No
    AllowedValues:
      - 'Yes'
      - 'No'
```

Otherwise, YAML (old version) will automatically convert `Yes/No` into `true/false`.